# Reverse mapping in aerospike

Tags: go, nosql, aerospike

I have a few records in aerospike in following key-value pair :

```
Key : "1234" 
Value : {
            "XYZ":{
                "B":[1,3]
                "C":[3,4]
            }
        }

Key : "5678" 
Value : {
            "XYZ":{
                "B":[1,3,5]
                "C":[3,4]
            }
        }
```

I want to get all the keys from set where field "B" in json value contains let say 3. Is there any way to query all such keys in golang ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can build a secondary index on the values in map key "B" ... at that nested level and then run a secondary index query to get all matching records.

You can do the same in Go using equivalent APIs.

Many Java interactive code examples at: https://developer.aerospike.com/tutorials/java/cdt_indexing

For example, this is top level example with string values:[image]

Then another example where you can build a SI on nested sublevel:
[image]